# How to retrieve method of a class in anonymous function?

Tags: php

How to retrieve method of a class in anonymous function? Does another opportunity exist to solve this?

Task:
I need to upload a image from remote path and change it to local path.

Code:

```
    $pattern = '/<img src=(.*?jpg|gif|png).*?>/m';

    $uploadImage = function($image)
    {
        $this->uploadPictures();
    };

    function image_replace($matches) use ($uploadImage)
    {
        // как обычно: $matches[0] -  полное вхождение шаблона
        // $matches[1] - вхождение первой подмаски,
        // заключенной в круглые скобки, и так далее...
        $uploadImage($matches[1]);

        return $matches[1].($matches[2]+1);
    }

    preg_replace_callback(
        $pattern,
        "image_replace",
        $text);
```

Comment: Which version of PHP do you using?

Comment: can you translate the comment part in your code?

Comment: @sinaneker Comment is not relevant to the problem. It just explains what `$match` contains.

Comment: @korvinko It seems that `$this` is used out of the scope. Can you update how that class looks?

Answer (score 1):

```
$pattern = '/<img src=(.*?jpg|gif|png).*?>/m';

$uploadImage = function ($image) {
    $this->uploadPictures();
};

$image_replace = function ($matches) use ($uploadImage) {
    $uploadImage($matches[1]);
    return $matches[1].($matches[2]+1);
};

preg_replace_callback($pattern, $image_replace, $text);
```

or

```
$pattern = '/<img src=(.*?jpg|gif|png).*?>/m';

$image_replace = function ($matches) {
    $this->uploadPictures($matches[1]);
    return $matches[1].($matches[2]+1);
};

preg_replace_callback($pattern, $image_replace, $text);
```

or

```
$pattern = '/<img src=(.*?jpg|gif|png).*?>/m';

preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($matches) {
    $this->uploadPictures($matches[1]);
    return $matches[1].($matches[2]+1);
}, $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the class object to the anonymous function

```
$uploadImage = function($image, $this)
{
    $this->uploadPictures();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

From PHP 5.4 `$this` can be used in anonymous functions (see changelog [here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)).

Thus, code such as this:

```php
<?php
class A
{
    public function test()
    {
        $f = function()
        {
            return $this->callback();
        };
        return $f();
    }

    public function callback()
    {
        return 'test';
    }
}

$a = new A();
echo $a->test();
```

is perfectly valid from 5.4 on.

In PHP 5.3 you could achieve the same thing using `use` operator:

```php
public function test()
{
    $_this = &$this;
    $f = function() use (&$_this)
    {
        return $_this->callback();
    };
    return $f();
}
```

Prior to PHP 5.3, you could avoid using `use` keyword through usage of function arguments:

```php
public function test()
{
    $f = function($_this)
    {
        return $_this->callback();
    };
    return $f($this);
}
```

Finally, when it comes to static methods, you could also make use of `__CLASS__` constant.

```php
public function test()
{
    $f = function()
    {
        return call_user_func(array(__CLASS__, 'callback'));
    };
    return $f();
}
```

...although it's quite ugly.